# How can I build Unity project from console/batch file/powershell file?

Tags: unity-game-engine, continuous-integration, build-automation

I am trying to automate Unity project builds but I cannot find a way to do it or any tutorial to guide me.
How can I build my Unity project from console or a batch file or a powershell file? Any of these will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to commandline documentation : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I actually did but forgot to update my question with an answer. You did it for me so you get the points :)